# Draw lines of increasing multiples based upon user entered variable, using a method

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm using A First Programming Course in Java by Tony Mullins as my learning resource. It's a very good book, but I'm stuck on the following problem :

Write a procedure that prints the first n rows of the following table:

```
2 
2 4
2 4 6 
2 4 6 8
```

Write a program to test this procedure.

I've figured out how to draw a numbered triangle (below), but I'm not sure how to get it with multiples e.g. 2,4,6, 8 etc.

Also the Q says 'first n rows'. Does this refer to a user entered input?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExQ4 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
    // Ask user to enter height

    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Please enter height : ");
    int height = userInput.nextInt();

    // Pass user input data into method
    drawMult (height);      
}


    // method for performing calculation of user data
    public static void drawMult (int height) {
        for (int i = 1; i<=height; i++){ 



    // Print space between the numbers  
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print(height);
        }

        System.out.println("");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: PS: It appears to have changed the formatting. The output should be on separate lines. Line 1 = 2; line 2 = 2, 4; line 3 = 2, 4, 6; line 4 = 2, 4, 6, 8 etc.

Comment: just double the height in drawMult

Comment: @Sionnach733: it's not the height that must be doubled. The height never changes. `j` must be doubled and printed.

Comment: Thanks guys.. doubling the height (e.g. if user inputs 2) outputs: 

Line 1: 4

Line 2: 44

Doubling j gives me line 1: 22; line 2: 44.

Comment: You must double j and print the result. i.e. print (2 * j) (followed by a space character)